# How to pass multiple array values in a Custom Adapter class for Custom List View?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with an image icon on the left and three text views on the right in a single row. I have created the layout, but while creating the adapter class I am facing some issues. Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[][] listRow;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[][] listRow, Integer[] imageId){
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, listRow);
    }
}
```

First I created three 1D arrays for the three textviews, but in the constructor I was not able to pass them all.

So I had to create a 2D array where every row in the table would represent information about a single list view item.

But I am not able to do so. I get an error:

> Cannot resolve method `super(android.app.Activity, int, java.lang.String[][])` with 2D arrays

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not a java dev but shouldn't it be `ArrayAdapter<String[]>` so that your listRow matches the type of the third parameter of the super class constructor?

Comment: The error tells you everything. There's no matching super constructor that takes the arguments you're trying to give it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: @TechnikEmpire yes I understand. But is there a way to pass multiple arrays or a 2d array to achieve the listview I wanted?

Comment: For complex views it is not recommended to use ArrayAdater but it's better to use BaseAdapter instead, in this case it's much easier to achieve your goal

Comment: @Chaosit can you please post an answer using the same so that we can have two alternate solutions?

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290854/447156

Comment: You can not pass a 2d array with the dimensions not set. you need to set at least the inner dimension.

Comment: @vals In Java? Really?

Comment: @glglgl    I worked for 15 years in COBOL, some day I will post there ...  :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After trying for a long time, I found the solution. I created a separate class to store the data values for each individual row and created an **array of objects** of the same.

Here is the sample code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

class ListItem
{
    public String textview1;
    public String textview2;
    public String textview3;
    public int imageId;

    public ListItem(String t1, String t2, String t3, int imageId)
    {
        this.textview1 = t1;
        this.textview2 = t2;
        this.textview3 = t3;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<Object>
{
    private Activity context;
    private ListItem listItem[];

    public CustomList(Activity context, ListItem li[])
    {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, li);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Good approach. Creating objects for storing data in more readable/OOP-ish way of doing things. This way you filter out possible confusions in the future.

Comment: Instead of making attribute public it is better to use get and setter methods. This is more preferred approach because we should not make our attributes public.

Answer (score 2):

Create a model class(separately) which contains all the three fields which are required. Then create arraylist in your activity and add items to it. pass this arraylist to adapter it works.

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding some example code, explaining how it works, or adding links to documentation which explains the code you use. A detailed answer like that is more likely to help others and will get you more upvotes as well ;)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I changed ArrayAdapter and It is working
You can change this code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String[]>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[][] listRow;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[][] listRow, Integer[] imageId){
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, listRow);
    }
}
```

**My code sample**

```
public class CustomAdepter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
    public CustomAdepter(@NonNull Context context, String[][] message) {
        super(context, R.layout.message_list, message);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list, parent, false);
        String singleMessage = getItem(position)[2];
        TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        textView.setText(singleMessage);
        return customView;
    }
}
```

See the change in `ArrayAdapter<String[]>, String[][] message` and `String singleMessage = getItem(position)[2];`